# Icon overlaps some usernames in chat

Tags: bug, chat, design

The display name of "*Nicolas Chabanovsky"* both goes under the logo, and the Mod Diamond goes onto another line.

> [image]

The same happens for another user too:

> [image]

Comment: And what does the graph and the blue line on the graph mean? (new in SE chat)

Comment: That's the activity graph, and the current time. It shows when ProgramFOX is usually active in chat. The full version in the user profile (first link in the popup) has larger versions of the same graph with a tooltip.

Comment: It's the `Typical user activity over a 24-hour period; current time is highlighted`